# Is there any way to do forward declaration when only working with one file

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, forward-declaration

I have 2 classes that depend on each other and I can't find a way to get forward declaration to work. I know how to do it using multiple cpp and header files, I was just curious if there's a way to do it in a single file.

```
class cls2;

class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1(cls2 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(cls1 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};
```

The error I get is:

```
error: 'p' has incomplete type
```

Comment: You have to define `cls1::cls1(cls2 p)` outside of  your `cls1` class after `class cls2 {};`

Answer (score 3):

Use references, that do not produce copies, thus no complete class declarations are required. And split method definitions, move them to the point where class declarations are complete.

```
class cls2;

class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1(const cls2& p);
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(const cls1& p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};

cls1::cls1(const cls2& p)
{
    vi = p.vi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message

```
error: 'p' has incomplete type
```

means that in the point of the constructor definition

```
cls1(cls2 p)
{
    vi = p.vi;
}
```

the compiler does not know yet how the class `cls2` is defined and whether it has the data member `vi`.

You can define constructors only when the class used as a parameter is a complete type.

For example

```
class cls2;

class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1(cls2 p);
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(cls1 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};

cls1::cls1(cls2 p)
{
    vi = p.vi;
}
```

Or instead of this forward declaration

```
class cls2;
```

you may use an elaborated type specifier in the constructor declaration of the class `cls1`

For example

```
class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1( class cls2 p);
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(cls1 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};

cls1::cls1(cls2 p)
{
    vi = p.vi;
}
```

It is interesting to note that using the constructors of the classes you can get an unexpected result.

For example for this declaration

```
cls1 c{ { 10 } };
```

there will be called this constrictor

```
cls1(int v = 30)
{
    vi = v;
}
```

But if you add one more pair of braces like this

```
cls1 c{ { { 10 } } };
```

then there will be called this constructor

```
cls1::cls1(cls2 p)
{
    vi = p.vi;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        std::cout << "cls1( int )\n";
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1( class cls2 p);
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(cls1 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};

cls1::cls1(cls2 p)
{
    std::cout << "cls1( cls2 )\n";
    vi = p.vi;
}

int main()
{
    cls1 c1 { { 10 } };
    cls1 c2 { { { 10 } } }; 

    // or
    // cls1 c1 { { } };
    // cls1 c2 { { { } } }; 
}
```

The program output is

```
cls1( int )
cls1( cls2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because the constructor needs to know how to copy the `cls2` object. You can solve this by moving the `cls1` constructor **implementation** after the `cls2` declaration:

```
class cls2;

class cls1
{
public:
    int vi;
    cls1(int v = 30)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls1(cls2 p);
};

class cls2
{
public:

    int vi;
    cls2(int v = 20)
    {
        vi = v;
    }
    cls2(cls1 p)
    {
        vi = p.vi;
    }
};


cls1::cls1(cls2 p) {
    vi = p.vi;
}
```